# creating a select element via js, focus doesn't work in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, focus, mootools, html-select

I'm a newbie in js and I'm afraid that i haven't the knowledge to resolve the next issue.

If I have a select element ( populated with several options ) already parsed by the browser on the load, the next code works just fine in both IE and FF

```
$('selectId').focus();
```

but if I create ( and populate it ) the element via js

```
var select = new Element('select',{ 'id':'selectId' });
~ etc. with options ~
select.focus();
```

the focus event doesn't work in IE. With FF is everything OK!

I've already tried various methods to workaround this issue but without good results!
Every time I need to click on the element to activate the focus event ( in IE ).

( yes, I use the mootools library! )

Any help will be very appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: is it correct to assume that you actually add the select drop down to the DOM?

Comment: yes my friend! ;)
The element is properly added in the DOM and works fine
except that in IE looses the focus I've given it.
Firebug and IE's console don't give any type of js error...
Thank you for the help!

Comment: can you reproduce the problem for us on jsbin.com?

Comment: of course!
check out the link
http://jsbin.com/elequ
you'll see the difference between IE and FF...
Thank you again!

Comment: that works for me, in IE8.  I double click on "click me", and then the second element, "one", is highlighted/in focus for me.  I can even use the up/down arrows to change it.

Comment: the jsbin page works fine for me in IE6, IE7 and IE8...
Try adding 
select.addEvent('focus',function(){alert('focusing');});
select.addEvent('blur',function(){alert('blurring');}); to see if something else steals the focus after your script finished creating the select

Comment: Hmmm... I'm using IE8 and 7 and I still have the problem.
1.You dblclick on the label
2.The open select appears with "one" selected
3.If you click on "two" you'll receive the alert with label "Two" in FF
4. If you click on "two" you'll receive the "one" in IE!

Can you please confirm that please? i checked in 2 different PCs!

Comment: @George - gosh, sure is strange.  I get the correct alert text in IE8 (no IE7 handy to test)

Comment: I'm afraid is too strange...
I tested it this morning ( at work ) using IE7
and I'm testing now with IE8 ( ver. 8.0.6001 ) with the same wrong alert message...
I need to post the clicked option via ajax and cause this issue I can't finish the project... it must work with both the browsers...

Comment: mate, you should not do element.value direct, particularily so on a select. do alert(this.get("value")); instead (for mootools 1.2, check http://mooshell.net/LUsQK/) i it also works on 1.11 which you are currently using -1.11 getter----->  this.getProperty("value"); good luck and upgrade to 1.2.4 tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Christoff
Thank you my friend!
I'm afraid that I must use the ver 1.11 of mootools because the project is based on the latest version of Joomla ( 1.5.14 ) which supports only the 1.11 mootools...
I've tried to call the click event right after the creation of the element ( as you have done in the sample ) and it seems to work, not 100%, but works.
The only issue is if you click the FIRST option, right after the appearance of the select, you'll get at the alert the value of the pre-selected! If you click any other option, the alert returns the right value! Strange! ( I always talk for the IE7-8 browser! )

Also, I copy-pasted the code from the mooshel to the jsbin.com ( http://jsbin.com/axuxi ) and it seems to have the same problem. The first click always return the value of the pre-selected...

Thank you for the help!

Comment: perhaps you are handling the wrong event here. i NEVER get the first option - in FF 3.5 and ie7. however, i suppose it is conceivable that the click event itself may fire before the onchange event, similarly to how onkeydown or onkeypress do. i refactored things a little here http://mooshell.net/tnYBY/ - through onfocus and onchange. it works reliably imo, but you may get the function run twice (for example, if you have lost focus, then click on a new option). p.s. you need firebug / console to see this, or replace with alerts..